# Color list of dataframes before exporting to excel

Tags: r

Hi my task is to make the data in Excel look presentable and readable when I export it. How do I color/beautify my dataframe using R in such a way that when I export the data to Excel it will look something similar to this? I would also like to export them into separate CSVs/xlsx based on their "Country"

[image: Formatted using Excel tools]

```
df = data.frame(Country = c("Japan", "Japan", "Thailand", "Germany", "Thailand", "Japan"), 
                            Count = c(15, 5, 25, 5, 60, 50))

#Separate the dataframe according to their respective country
splitdf = split(df, df$Country)

#Write multiple CSVs based on their filter
mapply(write.csv,splitdf,file=paste0(names(splitdf),'.csv'), row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Maybe this intro http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-xlsx-package-a-quick-start-guide-to-manipulate-excel-files-in-r to the `xlsx` might help you.

Comment: `write.csv` writes a CSV file, which has no formatting, no formulas, etc. It's just text, and nothing in the CSV "standard" allows you to do otherwise. If you want to format something so that Excel makes it look good, I suggest you use [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html). @holzben's recommendation to use [`xlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html) should also work, though anecdotally I see a lot more problems with `xlsx` related to its dependency on having java installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles aren't possible with `CSV` output. If you output to `xlsx`, you can [set styles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/vignettes/Formatting.html#use-of-pre-defined-table-styles) using `openxlsx`.

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Iris")
writeDataTable(wb, "Iris", iris, tableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2")
saveWorkbook(wb, "iris.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image: excel]

Here's the code for your example.

```
library(openxlsx)

save_data <- function(df, name) {
  wb <- createWorkbook()
  addWorksheet(wb, name)
  writeDataTable(wb, name, df, tableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2")
  saveWorkbook(wb, paste0(name, ".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
}

mapply(
  save_data,
  splitdf,
  names(splitdf)
)
```

Comment: Fantastic, just what I needed. Cheers!